# how to knit r markdown file for every 12 hours?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have the .Rmd file and it needs to be knit for every 12 hours also file name should include Sys.Date()-1.

below code i used and getting error :

```
rmarkdown::render("/home/saisaran/Project-2/Montly report.Rmd", 
                 output_file=sprintf('./DailyReports/LaunchDaily_%s.html', 
                 format(Sys.Date(), format = "%m-%d-%y")))
```

**error**

```
Error: path for html_dependency not found:
```

Comment: Which system are you on ? on windows you can schedule tasks with https://cran.r-project.org/package=taskscheduleR

Comment: Please post all your code. When I rerun this with the default `.Rmd` I get no error messages.

Comment: try also `dir.exists("'./DailyReports/")` and `file.exists("/home/saisaran/Project-2/Montly report.Rmd")`

Comment: i am using Ubuntu 18.04 and is there any simple method to achieve ?

Comment: I don't know Ubuntu, but you seem to have 2 issues to solve, a script which doesn't work, and scheduling the task, these would be better split into 2 questions, though I suspect the former is just doe to a typo or simple mistake on how to refer to the paths, have you tried the 2 commands I proposed above ?

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper i have tried and still getting the error , there is no error while i am trying to knit the document manually , it generated all the plots correctly.

Comment: these commands are not supposed to correct anything, they just tell you if your paths exist or not

Comment: For Ubuntu, try [cron jobs](https://www.google.com.au/search?newwindow=1&source=hp&ei=4ErZW56jA5DerQG47bmAAg&q=cron+job&oq=cron+job&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39k1l2j0i67k1l4j0i20i263k1j0i67k1l3.1206.2603.0.2789.9.8.0.0.0.0.388.1106.3-3.3.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..6.3.1105.0..0j0i131k1j0i131i67k1.0.91E3gf4T2cU)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got one link : how to schedule R scripts through r studio with cronR package for linux/Unix. still searching for more accurate methods..if anything will update here.

[R package details](http://www.bnosac.be/index.php/blog/64-scheduling-r-scripts-and-processes-on-windows-and-unix-linux)

**sample code**

```
library(cronR)
f <- system.file(package = "cronR", "extdata", "helloworld.R")
cmd <- cron_rscript(f, rscript_args = c("productx", "20160101"))
## Every minute
cron_add(cmd, frequency = 'minutely', id = 'job1', description = 'Customers')
## Every hour at 20 past the hour on Monday and Tuesday
cron_add(cmd, frequency = 'hourly', id = 'job2', at = '00:20', description = 'Weather', days_of_week = c(1, 2))
## Every day at 14h20 on Sunday, Wednesday and Friday
cron_add(cmd, frequency = 'daily', id = 'job3', at = '14:20', days_of_week = c(0, 3, 5))
## Every starting day of the month at 10h30
cron_add(cmd, frequency = 'monthly', id = 'job4', at = '10:30', days_of_month = 'first', days_of_week = '*')
## Get all the jobs
cron_ls()
## Remove all scheduled jobs
cron_clear(ask=FALSE)
```

Comment: partially working...for ubuntu need to find alternative solution

Comment: cron tasks work quite nicely on linux. I wonder if you have found any alternative for windows?